# Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

error line;

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<T, object>(ColumnProperty, pHtml.ViewData);
```

model

```
public class MenuAuths : EntityBase
{
[BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string MenuId { get; set; }
[BsonDefaultValue(false)]
        public bool AllowNew { get; set; }
}
```

cshtml;

```
new Column<LsDataModels.MenuAuths> { ColumnProperty = c => c.MenuId },
new Column<LsDataModels.MenuAuths> { ColumnProperty = c => c.AllowNew},
```

this line work     `new Column<LsDataModels.MenuAuths> { ColumnProperty = c => c.MenuId }`
but this line have an error  `new Column<LsDataModels.MenuAuths> { ColumnProperty = c => c.AllowNew},`

I can try property type change `bool?` , `bool` , `Nulable<bool>` but error has been continue. Also I remove `[BsonDefaultValue(false)]` attribute nothing change.

what can I do?

**Edit:** error is *Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solition for this problem.

I use `PropertyInfo`

I add exdent method on `Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>`

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(this Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> expression)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

            if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
            else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            }

            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");
            }

            return memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        }
```

and change this line

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<T, object>(ColumnProperty, pHtml.ViewData);
```

to

```
PropertyInfo pi = FieldProperty.GetProperty<T>();
```

I can access need all attributes and properties on `PropertyInfo`